# Este archivo no se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones posteriores

Tags: android, flutter

Has subido un APK o Android App Bundle que tiene una actividad, un alias de actividad, un servicio o un receptor de emisión con filtro de intents, pero sin establecer la propiedad android:exported. Este archivo no se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones posteriores. Consulta developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

En el archivo android/app/build.gradle hice coloque la version objetivo en 31 porque con la 30 ahora ya no deja subir a la tienda.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.f"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    resConfigs "en", "es"
}
```

Y el archivo AndroidManifest.xml ya he agregado el atributo android:exported="true", el archivo se ve asi:

```
<application    
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="Larvia"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false">
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      >
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: chequea esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting

Comment: He revisado las respuestas pero no me han sido utiles ,el problema sigue :c

Answer (score 1):

El problema que presentas, esta relacionado al siguiente error:

> "Has subido un APK o Android App Bundle que tiene una actividad, un
> alias de actividad, un servicio o un receptor de emisión con filtro de
> intents, pero sin establecer la propiedad android:exported. Este
> archivo no se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones posteriores.
> Consulta
> developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported"

en idioma inglés:

> Merge Errors Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified
> for element
> <activity#com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.checkout.CheckoutActivity>.
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an
> explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component
> has an intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

Se refiere a que todos los elementos en tu AndroidManifest.xml que contengan `intent-filter` deben tener definida la propiedad [**android:exported="true"**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=es-419#exported)

> [**android:exported="true"**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=es-419#exported) Determina si los componentes de otras
> aplicaciones pueden iniciar la actividad: Si es "true", cualquier app
> puede acceder a la actividad y se puede iniciar con su nombre de clase
> exacto. Si es "false", la actividad solo se puede iniciar con
> componentes de la misma aplicación, aplicaciones con el mismo ID de
> usuario o componentes del sistema con privilegios. Este es el valor
> predeterminado cuando no hay filtros de intents.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A todos los elementos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` ya sea activity, service, receiver, etc... que contengan "intent-filter" debes agregar `android:exported="true"`