# El APK que creo, una vez instalado en un movil me muestra el mensaje "La aplicación no está instalada"

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

Una vez creo mi archivo apk desde la terminal con "tns build android --compileSdk 33" y después de instalar ese apk en un móvil (sin mostrarse ningún error), al pinchar en el icono de la aplicación esta no se abre y se muestra el mensaje "La aplicación no está instalada".

La versión de Java que utilizo cuando estoy empaquetando la aplicación es la 20.0.1.

La versión de Gradle que tengo es la 8.4

Mi **build.gradle**, que se encuentra dentro de **app/** es el siguiente:

```
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 * This project uses @Incubating APIs which are subject to change.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
}

testing {
    suites {
        // Configure the built-in test suite
        test {
            // Use JUnit4 test framework
            useJUnit('4.13.2')
        }
    }
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(20)
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'xxxxxxxx.App'
}
´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el mensaje "La aplicación no está instalada" cuando tienes un icono de aplicación, indica que la app no se encuentre instalada, en realidad se tenía instalada, se trató de subir una nueva versión, eliminando la anterior versión pero ocurrió un error al instalarla. Por esta razón, lo que tu ves es el icono de la app pero no se puede abrir la misma.

Es importante que revises siempre si se construye tu proyecto sin mostrar mensajes de error en el LogCat o en la terminal, aunque en tu caso creaste el .APK usando la terminal:

```
 "tns build android  --compileSdk 33 --release --key-store-path C:\project\my-key.keystore --key-
```

store-password mypass --key-store-alias myaliasname --key-store-alias-password mypass"

de esta forma puede no ser tan facil obtener la información del posible error.

Te sugiero siempre uses el botón "Run App" primeramente para subir el dispositivo a tu emulador o dispositivo físico, de esta forma aseguras que tu .APK se creara corrrectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que comentas, se debe corregir si estas definiendo como target API Level 31 (Android 12) o posterior, debes definir a tus actividades, servicios, y receivers el atributo android:exported="true", ya que de otra forma no se instalará o se creará el .APK.

Revisa las siguientes respuestas:

[Error al actualizar Api 30 a 31](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/590953/95)

[Este archivo no se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones posteriores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/607775/95)

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido solucionar el problema...

El problema estaba en que en el `AndroidManifest.xml` tenía el `android:exported` en `"false"`, al ponerlo como `"true"` y empaquetar de nuevo el proyecto, ya se soluciona el problema.
Es decir:

```
android:exported="true"
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta x2